# R Using function Realoc with .C interface

Tags: c, r, memory-management, vector, dynamic-allocation

I am testing a call to a C function from R, using .C interface. The test consists in passing a numeric vector to the C function with no entries, dynamically allocates n positions, makes attributions and return the vector to R.

I'm using Calloc from R.h. The prototype of the function is

```
type* Calloc(size_t n, type)
```

as noted in Writing R Extensions.

The problem is that I don't get the new vector with the allocated positions in R. The vector continues to have no entries.

**The code in R**

```
fooR <- function(x) {
  if (!is.numeric(x))
    stop("argument x must be numeric")
  out <- .C("foo",
            x=as.double(x))
  return(out$x)
}

x <- numeric()

result <- fooR(x)
```

**The function in C**

```
#include <R.h>

void foo(double *x)
{
  int i, n;

  n = 4;
  x = Calloc(n, double);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    x[i] = i;
    printf("%f\n", x[i]); //just to check
  }
}
```

The question is: Can .C inteface handle with such memory allocation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use memory management that way but only if you use the `.Call()` interface instead of the `.C()` interface.

See the "Writing R Extensions" manual for [Memory Allocation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Memory-allocation) as well as [Interface Functions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eCall-and-_002eExternal).

There are other books, and a number of examples.  I prefer C++ over C, and with Rcpp we can hide all the mechanics:

```
 R> cppFunction('IntegerVector makeVec(int n) { return IntegerVector(n); }')
 R> makeVec(2)
 [1] 0 0
 R> makeVec(4)
 [1] 0 0 0 0
 R>
```

This uses both `.Call()` and R's memory allocation under the hood and is a quick little proof that "yes, you can" in fact create a vector dynamically.

Comment: If is true, tell me how it is possible to change an address of `x` that is "visible" at the outside of the `foo`? (with this signature of `foo`: `void foo(double *x)`)

Comment: Please read up on `.Call()` -- it takes and returns `SEXP` objects.  So we cannot accomodate your required signature with the interface given to us by R.

Comment: what about using Realloc() instead of Calloc(). I mean you send an array x (of double, for example) with n elements from R to C, via .C(), Realloc() it with, say, n + 10 elements, and use the new array x i R. Is it not possible to do this with .C() too, only with .Call()? In fact, that is what I'm trying to do. That is because the code in C that I have to change is large, and the work would be much easier using .C().

Comment: That would be in the same manual, in the same section that discusses `Calloc()`.  As I recall, it resizes *while dropping the content*.

Comment: Ok Dirk, thank you very much for the answer and comments. In fact, I have already read some stuff in Writing Extensions. But some passages are yet hard to me to understand. I'm going through the sections you point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know R language but I know C.

When you are taking a pointer to `x` as an argument in function `foo` then you can change content of `x` inside `foo` but not `x` itself.

If you want to change an address of `x` then you have to take "pointer to pointer to x" i.e. `**x`.

In your implementation of `foo` the compiler actually copy the value of `*x` i.e. memory address to `x` (compiler passes that address by value). So if you change the address inside the function then it remains unchanged at the outside.

Sorry, if I don't explain this clearly.

Anyway, in pure C the code should look like this:

```
void foo(double **x)
{
  int i, n;

  n = 4;
  *x = (double*) calloc(n, sizeof(double));

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    (*x)[i] = i;
    printf("%f\n", (*x)[i]); //just to check
  }
}
```

And here is the working snippet: https://ideone.com/mRsdUH

Comment: This answer is correct as far as C is concerned, but not applicable in the R context of the question asked here.

Comment: You have right. We don't want to redefine the wheel. In R language the magic behind SEXP already do the trick. BTW SEXP is just a pointer to this struct:
`typedef struct SEXPREC {
    SEXPREC_HEADER;
    union {
 struct primsxp_struct primsxp;
 struct symsxp_struct symsxp;
 struct listsxp_struct listsxp;
 struct envsxp_struct envsxp;
 struct closxp_struct closxp;
 struct promsxp_struct promsxp;
    } u;
} SEXPREC, *SEXP;`